# saving a class to NSUserDefaults in objc with NSCoding

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I am a little confused as to how i should proceed here, say this is my class

```
@interface PlayerStats : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
    NSMutableDictionary *gameStats;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs;

    GamePlayStats *_gamePlayStats;

    GameStats *_openGameStats;
    GameStats *_duelGameStats;
    GameStats *_challengeGameStats;

    float _averagePanelsRevealed;
    float _averageGuessSpeed;

    int _totalCoinsEarned;
    int _totalTokensEarned;

    int _playerLevel;
}
```

now when i want to save the class i wish to do it this way as it seems more sensible to just save the class and when i get it back i can just call it's variables though it's methods etc , etc.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self forKey:@"playerStats"];
}
```

However all the examples i have seen require you to load all the variables in individually so it should looke something more like

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.gamePlayStats forKey:@"gamplaystats"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self._openGameStats forKey:@"openGameStats"];
    etc..
}
```

is there a reason for why this is the case?

cheers

Comment: Not sure if you've made a typo or what but you would not write something like: self._ivarname. Calling something with self. assumes you are accessing a property and the "_"prefix is usually used for ivar names and not property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder ask you to decide which variable you want to save to the encoder. The information encoder generates for you is the class information. Inside [encoder encodeObject:aObject forKey:@"key"], it will try to call the [aObject encodeWithCoder:encoder]. I think if write encodeWithCoder: like

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self forKey:@"playerStats"];
}
```

Will write nothing but your class's name and class type, because apple has enabled the reference checking in the coder, it won't encode the same object twice. Otherwise the encodeWithCoder on the same object will be called many times.

Therefore, you have to encode necessary properties/variables into the encoder to save the class's data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract from Apple's doc on NSCoding protocol:  In keeping with object-oriented design principles, an object being encoded or decoded is responsible for encoding and decoding its instance variables.  You can read the full text on [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

For your sample snippet, you need to follow the latter one.  Also, the GamePlayStats and
GameStats classes also needed to conform to be NSCoding protocol as well.